# UK Standard Visit Visa - "What is the total amount of money you spend each month?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for a Standard UK Visit Visa and during filling in the application form, I came across the question in the title but am not sure what this question refers to since it's not very clear.

They asked me about the average of money that I spend in my home country ?
Or the money that I will spend in UK?

Answer (score 3):

That means the average amount of money you spend in your current country of residence, not UK. This question is to ascertain your finances and to check whether you can afford this trip.